# Is there a way to specify the character encoding to the java.lang.StringBuilder

Tags: java, character-encoding

Or am I stuck with :

```
String s = new String(new byte[0], Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
// or ISO_8859_1, or LATIN-1 or ... still no constants for those
for (String string : strings) { // those are ISO-8959-1 encoded
    s += string; // hopefully this preserves the encoding (?)
}
```

Comment: Text written to or read from a File or Stream is what can be specifically encoded.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Strings are *always* UTF-16-encoded in Java. They're *just* sequences of `char` values, which are UTF-16 code units. When you specify the encoding to the `String(byte[], String)` constructor, it's *just* saying how to decode the bytes into text - the encoding is discarded afterwards.

If you need to preserve an encoding, you'll need to create your own class to keep a `Charset` and `String` together. I can't say that I've ever wanted to do that though - are you really sure you need to?

(So your "stuck with" code wouldn't work anyway - and it would also be inefficient.)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: The "your" was correct to start with - the code in the question "belongs" to the OP. "You're" just doesn't work in this context.

Comment: "your "stuck with" code wouldn't work anyway - and it would also be inefficient" - that's why I said stuck - thanks for the answer I think now I digested it !

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: "Or am I stuck with" suggests to me that you've got code which you dislike, but would work around the problem - in this case it would have *no* benefits. Glad you've "got it" now though :)

Answer (score 2):

How about to use converter with caching:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1<<10);
    OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
    try {
        osw = new OutputStreamWriter(baos, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
    }
    osw.write("Привет!");
    osw.flush();
    System.out.println("Hello: " + baos.toString("UTF-8"));
}
```